# How does Android-studio change lists feature work behind the scenes with git

Tags: git, android-studio, version-control

How is the IDE actually interacting with git to achieve this. Is it using `git stash` or it's own logic within the IDE to keep track of changes?

If you know of a 3rd party tool git gui tool outside of android studio that has same functionality that would be a nice (comment better?) but a CLI workflow answer would be awesome.

[image]

Comment: What role does Subversion play here?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I think the 'changelist' concept comes from svn http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.ref.svn.c.changelist.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Changelists](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/managing-changelists.html) are stored in the IDE project folder, more specifically the `.idea/workspace.xml` file. For example:

```xml
<component name="ChangeListManager">
  <list default="true" id="2cc87e04-1ce7-4d2f-8a15-4c2d911f9f2d" name="Default Changelist" comment="" />
  <list id="05f3faae-0ca6-45f7-94b2-2c5396e1a517" name="MyNewChangelist" comment="">
    <change afterPath="$PROJECT_DIR$/index.php" afterDir="false" />
  </list>
</component>
```